# Не логиниться в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio

Создал в админке учётную запись, после чего установили Android Studio 2.2(возможно как то связано). Выбило на главный экран с учетными записями, после чего нельзя зайти в созданную учёткИ(создавал дважды) - пробовал через Ctrl + Alt + F1 вводить логин, пишет *login is incorrect*.
В админку + guest заходит без проблем(Ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: Залогиньтесь, проверьте вывод `sudo passwd -aS`. При необходимости сбросьте пароль: `sudo passwd [USERNAME]`.

Comment: Создай учетку под другим именем (не тем что ты создавала ранее), если в нее заходит - делаем выводы. Так же попробуй создать учетку через консоль, а не через админку